# cannot make second inflate on google map using tablet

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

When I try to inflate on the second time when I use my tab the app crashes, on a small device its working. I am trying to inflate on the google map fragment. The fragment is inside. I tried to kill my map fragment before I relapse but it didn't work When I try to go from onList_ItemClickListener  to map fragment the app crashes

my conteiner xml

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablet_left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:background="#eeeeee" >



        </FrameLayout>


       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablet_rigth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

my main class :

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements  Search_Categories.onCategoryClickListener,
                    First_Page.onSearchTypeListener,
                    Search_Fragment.OnListResultClickListener,
                    Search_Fragment.onGetAllPlacesClickListener
    {
        boolean isTablet;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.container); 

            isTablet = isTablet(getApplicationContext());

            if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null){

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
                }
                First_Page first = new First_Page();
                first.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, first).commit();

            }else{
                First_Page first = new First_Page();
                first.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tablet_left, first).commit();

                Map_fragment map = new Map_fragment();
                map.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tablet_rigth, map).commit();

            }   

        }



        @Override
        public void onList_ItemClickListener(String lat, String lng, String placeName,String placeRating, String placeAdress) {
            isTablet = isTablet(getApplicationContext());   
            if (isTablet==true){    
                Map_fragment map_frag2 = new Map_fragment();
                Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
                bundel.putString("lat", lat);
                bundel.putString("lng", lng);
                bundel.putString("name", placeName);
                bundel.putString("rating", placeRating);
                bundel.putString("adress", placeAdress);

                map_frag2.setArguments(bundel);

                FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction1.replace(R.id.tablet_rigth, map_frag2);
                transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction1.commit();

            }else{
                // phone
                //need to change view bundel
                Map_fragment map_frag = new Map_fragment();
                //Search_Fragment search = new Search_Fragment();
                Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
                bundel.putString("lat", lat);
                bundel.putString("lng", lng);
                bundel.putString("name", placeName);
                bundel.putString("rating", placeRating);
                bundel.putString("adress", placeAdress);
                map_frag.setArguments(bundel);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, map_frag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();                   
            }                           
        public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
            boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
            boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
            return (xlarge || large);
        }
    }
```

my map fragment

```
    public class Map_fragment extends Fragment{

         private GoogleMap googleMap;
         DBHandler placesDB;

         FavoritDBHandler favoritsDB;


         GPSTracker gps;

            double myLat;
            double myLng;

            String placeRating;
            String placeAdress="no adress in the system";
            String placename="No name";
            double latitude = 32.0833;
            double longitude = 34.8000;

            String lat;
            String lng;
            boolean isTablet=false;
            boolean flag=true;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            favoritsDB = new FavoritDBHandler(getActivity());


            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            boolean get_All_Places_Flag = false;


            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();
                Bundle bundel = getArguments();
                lat = bundel.getString("lat");
                lng= bundel.getString("lng");
                placename = bundel.getString("name");
                placeAdress= bundel.getString("adress");
                placeRating= bundel.getString("rating");
                get_All_Places_Flag=bundel.getBoolean("flag");


                latitude = Double.valueOf(lat);
                longitude =  Double.valueOf(lng);


                gps= new GPSTracker(getActivity());   
                myLat = gps.getLatitude();
                myLng = gps.getLongitude();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            ImageButton navigate = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.navigate);
            navigate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   
                    LatLng start=new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
                    LatLng end=new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    Navigator navy = new Navigator(googleMap,start,end);
                    navy.findDirections(true);

                }
            });


            boolean isTablet=false;
            gps= new GPSTracker(getActivity());
            myLat = gps.latitude;
            myLng = gps.longitude;

            isTablet= isTablet(getActivity());
            if (isTablet==true){
                if(flag==true){
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        new LatLng(myLat, myLng)).zoom(13).build();
                    setGoogleMap(cameraPosition);
                    flag=false;

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLat,myLng)).title("You Are Here")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "may lat" +myLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    // ADD marker to map
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(placename));
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLat,myLng)).title("You Are Here")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                }


            }else{
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(15).build();
                setGoogleMap(cameraPosition);

              // ADD marker to map
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(placename));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myLat,myLng)).title("You Are Here")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            }





        }



        private void setGoogleMap(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);   
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // false to disable   
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        }




        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            SupportMapFragment map1 = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(map1 != null)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(map1).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if (map != null){ 
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(map).commit();
            }
        }



        public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
            boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
            boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
            return (xlarge || large);
        }

    }
```

CHANGES IN THE CODE 
               @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

```
            SupportMapFragment map = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("google_map");
            if (map != null){ 
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(map).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }

            /*Map_fragment map = (Map_fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("google_map");
            if (map != null){ 
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(map).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }*/

        }
```

my MAP CLASS XML:

```
        <fragment
            android:tag="google_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map"

        >
         </fragment>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/navigate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/location_50" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_to_favorits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/location_star_50" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/location_speech_bubble_50" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/place_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/location_info_50" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe show some LogCat?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Duplicate id 0x7f060021, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment